# Simplest Way of Rounding Up the Average in C++

Tags: c++, rounding

```
int a, b, c = 0;
c = (a+b)/2;
```

In this code, if both "a" and "b" are even (Example 1), then there's no problem. But if one of them is **odd** (Example 2), then the answer will have +0.5. I want to round it up.

**Example 1.**

a=4, b=10

c will be = **7** This is OK.

**Example 2.**

a=3, b=4

c will be = **3.5**
And I want c to be rounded up and become **4** instead.

Comment: FYI: `int a, b, c = 0;` only initializes `c`, not `a` or `b`. Also of note: `c` can't be `3.5` since you are doing integer division (and because `c` is also an `int`, too).

Comment: Check the following link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/. In the link example it shows the difference between round, floor, ceil, trun functions. Have a look at example and use the function according to your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make `c` a `double`, then use

`c = (a + b)/2.0`

otherwise you have truncation due to division of `int`s being casted to `int`. In this way, `(a + b) / 2.0` is a `double`, due to the denominator being a `double`, so you don't have any truncation.

Next, use the function `std::round` from C++11, or `std::floor/std::ceil`, depending on what exactly you want

Alternatively, you can keep `c` and `int` but do

```
c = std::round( (a + b) / 2.0 ); // rounding to nearest integer, C++11
```

or

```
c = std::floor( (a + b) / 2.0 ); // rounding down
```

or

```
c = std::ceil( (a + b) / 2.0 ); // rounding up
```

If you don't want any warnings, can also explicitly cast the result of `std::floor/std::ceil/std::round` back to `int`, like

```
c = static_cast<int>(std::round( (a + b) / 2.0 )); // now we tell the compiler we know what we're doing
```

Comment: Please if you downvote say why. The solution is verbose, it doesn't add any significant overhead, and it is correct.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, it violates some fundamental best practice. Converting integers to floats should always be avoided if at all possible. While the overhead is minimal, it is still present and is worth noting. Further, there are many problems that can occur in the realm of floats that one wouldn't expect. At the extremes, floats lose granularity over their values, and can lead to unexpected issues, especially as the delta value grows larger.

Comment: @Kaslai it is a complete nonsense in my opinion. The functions above are extremely well tested, and probably implemented internally as Sebastian wrote. We don't talk here about numerical analysis where yes you care about precession etc, but we talk about a simple rounding question. There is 0 danger here using `double`s I bet the functions are even inlined, so you have almost 0 overhead, if not 0.

Comment: It's important to be aware of the potential issues though. With a 32 bit float, any value that is larger than 2^23 will fail to round up correctly using this technique, and a 64 bit float will fail at 2^52. This can be a serious issue if you're dealing with numbers like that, which isn't necessarily outside the realm of common usage. Especially in financial applications, things like this can cause serious damage. I'm not saying that this particular question requires 100% accuracy, but it's very important to make note of such things.

Comment: @Kaslai, I agree that there are issues, but you should care about them when indeed you **need** to care about them. And I am not sure that I understand "With a 32 bit float, any value that is larger than 2^23 will fail to round up correctly using this technique". You have `int + int` that is being converted to `double`, so the only problem here is `int` overflowing, which can appear also on the `a + b +1` trick.

Comment: 2^23 is a much lower value than the (more or less) standard 32 bit int most people will be using though. Addition is guaranteed to require no more than one extra bit of precision, so you're more likely to have erroneous floats before you hit an integer overflow. The code you supply will definitely not have issues since you're converting ints to doubles, but it still violates best practice. Also, integer overflows are almost always quickly diagnosable. Issues that arise from floating point inaccuracy are often subtle and hard to catch, especially if it's a problem with an intermediate value.

Comment: @Kaslai ok, I guess I have a different opinion than yours. And yes, I don't use any `float` here, the result is implicitly converted to `double`, so I don't even see how the `float` came into picture. The code I wrote may have problems *only if* double overflows before `int`, which is never the case. And integer overflow will still be diagnosed (note that I am not converting inside the sum `a + b`)

Comment: Float was just shorthand for floating point number. The size of floats is system dependent, so there's no guarantee that integer <-> float conversions will work how you expect them to.

Comment: Ok, ok, I should have said "which is seldom the case", as `double` is guaranteed to be at least as large as `float` (the latter can be smaller than `int`, but again I still have to see an implementation where it is). And the whole issue becomes a problem for large numbers. In that case you need to be careful, however this question didn't ask anything about overflowing etc. I use code like the above quite often, and in the long run I find it easier to read/debug. When using finite precision in a numerical system you have to be careful, but I assume one is aware of overflowing issues.

Comment: apart from the correctness, there's a performance penalty of these conversion, so (a+b+1) is a better solution, the question is only dealing with int, involving floating point types are unnecessary

Answer (score 8):

First off, you're wrong. `c` is an integer, so it can't be 3.5. Furthermore, `a`, `b` and 2 are all integers, so the division is integer division, so it can't result in 3.5 either. It will be rounded towards zero, so it will be 3.

That said, to get integer division by 2 to round up instead of down, simply add 1 before dividing. `(14 + 1) / 2 == 7`, so that's still right. `(7 + 1) / 2 == 4`, so that's correct too.

Comment: It's worth noting that this can be extended to a general case, too. Simply adding `divisor - 1` to the result before division will obtain the effect of a `ciel` operation in integer arithmetic without incurring the overhead of running the same operation twice, along with a modulus operation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ceil](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/) function. It will always round up whatever number you put in it.

Comment: `ceil` will only work in the case of floating point arithmetic though. The integer arithmetic won't be affected at all by `ceil`.

Comment: but it will return double or float, not a int.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to use `+ 1` after the result if the result is not round (what the `ceil` function would do by default for you)

```
int a, b, c = 0;
if ((a + b) % 2 == 1)
   c = ((a+b)/2) + 1;
else
   c = (a+b)/2;
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/AmgDUt

Comment: If you were to do that, then his first example would give the result of 8, which is incorrect.

Comment: The attempted fix still doesn't fix the problem; you wanted `(a + b) % 2`, not `((a + 2)/2) % 2`.

Comment: Which just goes to show that too much code just invites bugs. And your most recent edit is incorrect, that's not what `ceil` does.

Comment: @wolfPack88 @"Sebastian Redl" you're right, I'm stumbling around here

Comment: @Vinzenz Test-driven development - in this case, the test is the feedback here. ;-)

Comment: @"Sebastian Redl" yes, sorry for "abusing" you :( . I made an only Demo to test it now :) https://ideone.com/AmgDUt

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to use the [`ceil()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/) function from `<math.h>`.

```
int a, b, c = 0;
c = (int) ceil((float)(a+b)/2);
```

Comment: Downvoter? Added the `int` cast. Please specify what's wrong.

Comment: this doesn't work, as `(a+b)/2` will be converted to `int`. You need to do `(a+b)/2.0`, to get a `double`, then use `ceil`

Comment: Edited. Added the `float` cast.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a, b, c = 0;
c = (a+b+1)/2;
```